# Flash support for packaged chrome apps

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, flash, google-chrome-app

I want to use flash contents in my chrome packaged app (at least for an year), but Flash is listed as a disabled feature in [chrome app developer site](https://developer.chrome.com/apps/app_deprecated), which means we cannot use flash directly in a chrome packaged app.

But still we can use flash contents inside a web view. I have some chrome packaged apps in development process which takes advantage of this. But I'm concerned about the future, will it gonna support  in the future as well?

Comment: Difficult to see. Always in motion is the future.